# How to get a string from a website and append some text after it in javascript

Tags: javascript, web

I want to get a specific string from the whole HTML document, store it in a variable and replace it with another string based on the original string.
I tried the search function in javascript but it only returns the index of the first character, I want the whole string, some way to search and get the index of the last character of the string, then I can get the whole string.

Comment: *"I tried the search function"* Can you include your attempt(s)? That way we can help you understand what is going wrong. -> [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I think you're accessing DOM incorrectly maybe this could help you out https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.